# Is there a way to make actions optional in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

This is a bit of a newbie question, but... is there a way to make actions optional in Selenium IDE? I'll provide a use case.

In the app I'm testing, users see a "hey, you're agreeing to the ToS by logging on"-type modal window at the beginning of each session. They have to click OK to continue, and they don't see the window again until the next session.

Based on what I've seen so far, I need to have one test suite for the first test each day, and a second test suite for all the others. The second suite is exactly the same except that it doesn't have the "click okay to dismiss the initial modal window" step. Alternatively, I could just remember that my first run of the test each day will fail, and that I have to run the test again.

Both of those "solutions" seem unnecessarily awkward. Can I just make the `click` command optional?

Answer (score 4):

Create a javascript file called user-extensions.js with the below code. Then go into the Selenium IDE Options dialog and select your user-extensions.js file, restart Selenium and you'll be able to choose TryClick which will work the same as Click but suppress any errors.

```
Selenium.prototype.doTryClick = function(locator) {
    try {
        return Selenium.prototype.doClick.call(this,locator);
    } catch(err) { return null; }   
};
```

Answer (score 3):

*Perhaps overdue, but for future searchers.*

You could use the **if** and **endIf** statements within the IDE.

Comment: if and endIf actually refers to commands provided by the SelBlocks extensions: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cookies to decide whether to hide the ToS dialog, you could check that a certain cookie is set and if so, skip the click.

I haven't used the selenium IDE much, but I think doing the check would be much easier if you are using a programming language. I am not sure how to do it in HTML tests.

If you are using HTML, you could have a look for [Selenium IDE Flow Control](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/flowControl) and see if that can do what you need. I haven't used this myself, but if looks like it supports if statements. You could use verifyCookie to check if the cookie exists.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hm, good idea. I'll give this a try. I take it you don't know of a command to check for cookie settings? +1 either way.

Comment: When you say "cookie settings", what do you mean? To view the cookies set for a page, you could use [getCookie](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getCookie%28%29)

Comment: Just had another thought - you could use embedded javascript to do the checking.

Answer (score 1):

As aj.esler pointed it out Selenium ID Flow control is a good solution that has worked for me.
Here is the [Firefox add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flow-control/)
I use the **gotoif**, here is an example about how you can use it. When skip value is 1 then it will go to the label=jump line and will not execute everything from gotoif like to label=jump .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another  extremely useful flow control add-on for the IDE is [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/)

It will give you the ability to use: `if/else/for/foreach/while` and even a way to read variables from an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/flowControl addon.
Make something like this :

```
1.storeElementPresent | //button[@name="cookie_law_accept"] | cookie_law
2.goToIf | storedVars['cookie_law']!=true | end
3.click | //button[@name="cookie_law_accept"]
4.label | end
```

Explain:
1.If element is present it will be stored as a "cookie_law" with value "true"
2.If cookie_law is not "true" - go to label "end" - other way go to next step
3.Click to cookie accept button (only when it`s`enter code here`present because it it`s not - you go to "end" label and you skip this command)
4.You go here if there is no cookie law button :)